# Extract current folder name within maven pom.xml file

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, jenkins-plugins

I am looking for a way to dynamically extract the current folder name within maven pom.xml file.

For Example:
if the pom.xml file is at /home/jenkins/workspace/bdms-ci/bdms-bcr/pom.xml
then bdms-bcr is the current folder.

See a code snippet:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <testClassesDirectory>../../bdms-ci-improve/${project.basedir}/target/test-classes</testClassesDirectory>
        <classesDirectory>../../bdms-ci-improve/${project.basedir}/target/classes</classesDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

${project.basedir} will bring the full path which is not good since only the current folder is needed.

I tried to work with MavenProject class from the maven api document:
${project.file.parentFile.name} or ${project.file.name}, but it didn't work.

remember it is maven multi project and everything has to be dynamically.
The whole issue is for jenkins ci build which use parallel-test-executor plugin. I would like to compile once in the main job and then all the other test execute jobs will will only test by looking into the compiled code.

Using maven 3.2.3

Comment: Why do you want to configure this way? Because you want the target classes to be put in a different folder from the conventional ones?

Comment: As explained in the question but I will try to go into more details. There is a new jenkins plugin that can run unit test in different workspace (parallel-test-executor) which means it runs n parallel. The plugin assumes that unit tests are in different maven module then the source code which is not the case in most maven projects. Because of that I prefer to compile the code once and only then to call the plugin to execute all the test in parallel with surefire:test phase by configuring the plugin to include the compiled jenkins project in its classpath .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do it. simple as that.
A workaround solution is by using artifactId with the same name as folder name. then you can do:

```
../../bdms-ci-improve/${project.artifactId}/target/test-classes</testClassesDirectory>
```

Answer (score 0):

@guymi,

Seems like you should be able to simply use `${project.artifactId}` or perhaps `${parent.artifactId}`.

**EDIT**

Or does your artifactId name disagree with the directory it's stored in?

If so, that's possible but not good practice and should be avoided.

Comment: It is not possible to force developers to create artifactId with the same name as the folder name. If there is no answer to what am I looking for then that will be a solution